# How can i access icloud drive files in simulator with react-native-fetch-blob

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-fetch-blob, react-native-fs

i have tried using react-native-fs to do the same but was suggested that we cant access icloud with -fs. Please, if i can with react-native-fetch-blob, then i need some suggestions of how do i implement it.

Answer (score 0):

To access your ICloud drive using react-native-fetch-blob in ios, I am pretty sure you need a developers account.